# Why does slash in the end of URL affect ElasticSearch results drastically?

Tags: elasticsearch

I was faced with a pretty weird problem using ElasticSearch. Hope somebody will help me or will give me a piece of advice.

I have an index with a field 'url' which is feeled with 'uax_url_email' tokenizer. I save URLs there. Some URLs in 'url' field have slashes in the end and some - not.

For example I have 2 docs with the following values in 'url' field:

- Doc 1. url = https://google.com/xyz/
- Doc 2. url = https://google.com/abc

1. If I search for text 'https://google.com/xyz' it works fine.
2. If I search for text 'https://google.com/xyz/' it also works fine.
3. If I search for text 'https://google.com/abc' it also works fine.
4. **But** if I search for text 'https://google.com/abc/' (with the slash in the end) Elastic can't find a Doc 2.

For example, the score for (3) could be 28 and the score for (4) could be 3 (8 times less!).

What is wrong with this?  Why the slash at the end of the URL is making such a drastic difference in the score?

Comment: Can you show the mapping definition of the `url` field (with the analyzer definition as well)?

Comment: You might use [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/_testing_analyzers.html) to see how is it actually representing the URL internally.